# Extjs change the color of the cell outline in grid

Tags: extjs, grid, cell

change the color of the cell outline in grid depending on the editable value in this cell. I understand that you need to listeners 'change'/'afterchange'  edit css-style.  tell me how to do it

```
      columns: [{
         text: 'code', 
        dataIndex: 'code', 
        flex: 1, 
        align: 'center' }, 
        { 
       text: 'source', 
        hidden: true, 
        dataIndex: 'code_source', 
        flex: 2, align: 'center', 
        renderer: function (value, metaData) { metaData.tdAttr = 'data-qtip="' + 
       value + '"'; return value; } }, 
        { text: 'value', 
        dataIndex: 'value', 
        flex: 3, 
        align: 'center', 
        editor: { xtype:'textfield', allowBlank: false, minLength: 1, maxLength: 
        255 }, 
       renderer: function (value, metaData) { if(!value){ value = ''; } 
       metaData.tdAttr = 'data-qtip="' + value + '"'; return value ? value : ''; 
       } 
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change style of column using `renderer` function in grid column.

```
renderer : function(value, meta) {
    if(value === "smth") {
        meta.style = "border-color:green;border-width:2px"; // extra style here
    }
    return value;
}
```

Comment: this will not work, please see the sample code, I added above